Application keeps asking for permissions to display notifications after restarting simulator or reloading it in the terminal
I am developing an application in react native. I allow notifications. but when I take the application down from the simulator and re-enter it or reload it again with the 'r' command in the terminal, it asks for permission on the same page.
Here are my codes
 const checkAndRequestNotificationPermission = async () => {
        try {
            const storedPermission = await AsyncStorage.getItem('notificationPermission');
            
            if (storedPermission === 'granted') {
                return;
            }
    
            const { status: existingStatus } = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
            
            if (existingStatus === 'granted') {
                await AsyncStorage.setItem('notificationPermission', 'granted');
                return;
            }
    
            if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
                Alert.alert(
                    promotion.t('notificationTitle'),
                    promotion.t('notificationMessage'),
                    [
                        {
                            text: promotion.t('notificationCancel'),
                            style: "cancel",
                            onPress: async () => {
                                await AsyncStorage.setItem('notificationPermission', 'denied');
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            text: promotion.t('notificationAllow'),
                            onPress: async () => {
                                const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
                                await AsyncStorage.setItem('notificationPermission', status);
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                );
            } else {
                const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
                await AsyncStorage.setItem('notificationPermission', status);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error requesting notification permission:', error);
        }
    };

react native notification management

FYI: There is no actual question here...
